# Issue while trying to convert dic value to currency value

Tags: ios, swift, currency, nsnumber, numberformatter

I have a dictionary with Bill Price as Optional Any
My issue is that I want to convert it in Currency with the function below:

```
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current
let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: ToConvert2)
print(priceString) // Displays $9,999.99 in the US locale
```

Im using the following data:
`dicType.value(forKey: "BON_PRIX")`
--> Optional  - some : 103.28

I tried:

```
let ToConvert = (String(describing: dicType.value(forKey: "BON_PRIX") as! String))
let ToConvert2 = NSNumber(value: Int(ToConvert)!)
```

but I'm getting Fatal error,

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I tried few things but didn't find the right way.
So the point is to convert data from an external server into EUR with roundup with 2 decimals.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It's unclear which line is crashing. `let ToConvert = ...` or `let ToConvert2 = ...` ? It can change everything. Also, if it's the second one, what's `ToConvert` then? Plus why use `value(forKey:)`? Why forcecasts? Why uppercase on var names?

Comment: The problem is that `dicType.value(forKey: "BON_PRIX")` is nil, so is failing when trying to unwrap it (!). You should do something like `if let value = dicType.value(forKey: "BON_PRIX") as? double {let ToConvert2 = NSNumber(value: value) }` this will prevent your error.

Comment: Hello Larme, ToConvert2 is crashing

Comment: Are you sure that the value for key `BON_PRIX` is `String`? It seems to be `Double`. And you are misusing both `value(forKey` and `String(describing`. And even creating an `Int` from a `Double` with decimal places crashes.

Comment: Yes BON_Prix is String and with ```let ToConvert = Float(String(describing: dicType.value(forKey: "BON_PRIX") as! String))! ``` I return 103.28, the issue is that an NSNumber is required for ```let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: ToConvert as! NSNumber)```

Comment: Then you don't do `ToConvert as! NSNumber`. You don't cast, it won't work. Instead, use the init method of NSNumber from a float. Or a Double depending on what you use.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `NSNumber`:

```
let value = dicType["BON_PRIX"] as? String
// safely convert String to Double
let roundedDoubleValue = value.flatMap { Double($0) }
// use .string(for:) instead of .string(from:)
let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(for: roundedDoubleValue }) ?? ""
```

Comment: hello Sulthan, thats almost that `let roundedDoubleValue = value.flatMap { Double($0) }.map { round($0) } `did almost the job, I don't have error any more but I received 103 and should be 103,28.

Comment: @jo7332 Oh, just remove the rounding part then. I thought you wanted to round that but you can do that using the formatter anyway. Updated.

Comment: Tks Sulthan, that did the job. Im new in Xcode and didn't know that `flatmap`, I'm not really understand why that's working now and why the  `NSNumber(value: Int(ToConvert)!) `didn't work. Tks for your help. If someone have other solution just as extra info I will be glad to learn other code line  also. Tks

Comment: @jo7332 You cannot use `Int` because `ToConvert` does not contain an integer number. Therefore `Int("1.02")` will return `nil` and `!` after a `nil` will make it crash. You could technically fix your problem simply by converting `Int(...)` to `Double(...)` but it would still be too complicated and unsafe.

Answer (score -1):

```
func getEuro(strVal: String) -> String? {

   let doubleStr = Double(strVal)

   let price = doubleStr as? NSNumber

   print(price)

   let formatter = NumberFormatter()

   formatter.numberStyle = .currency

   // Changing locale to "es_ES" for Spanish Locale to get Euro currency format.

   formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES")

   if let price = price {
      let euroPrice = formatter.string(from: price)
      print(euroPrice!) //"103,28 €"

      return euroPrice
   }

   return nil
}

print(getEuro(strVal: "103.28")) //Optional("103,28 €")
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but I want to use the function that allow me to do round up and convert in currency.

Comment: Why would you set locale to `es_ES`?

Comment: es_ES is for Spanish locale which has Euro currency

Comment: @Amyth Why would you change locale, therefore the whole formatting (decimal separators, currency symbol etc.) instead of just setting `currency = "EUR"`?

Comment: @Sulthan , is setting currency = "EUR" working for you?.  Changing the locale is a good choice here as we want our currency to have separators, currency symbol and properly formatted.

Comment: @Amyth Of course setting `numberFormatter.currencyCode = "EUR"`  will work. That's the whole purpose of the property. Changing locale to change currency is not a good idea. Why would you overwrite user locale?

Comment: @Sulthan, if we change formatter.currencySymbol = "€" , we will get " € 103.28 " but we want 103,28 €

Comment: @Sulthan, you are right! User locale should not be changed frequently. I have updated my answer. It will not modify user's primary locale.

Comment: @Amyth You know that the position of the symbol is dependent on language? If the device is set to English (therefore it has currency symbol before amount), why do you want to enforce a different formatting? Even changing `currencySymbol` directly is kind of nasty because every language uses a different symbol.